# Log errors in a file

Tags: erlang

How do I log all process crashes into a file instead of a tty ? I've read in the documentation that there are some standard Erlang modules that can do it (SASL, error_logger), but unfortunately haven't found any clean examples.

Comment: Is this for you as a developer or for production use?  I'm no Erlang expert, but if it's just for you, you could probably just redirect STDOUT to a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start your erl node with

```
erl -boot start_sasl -sasl sasl_error_logger \{file,\"path/to/logfile.log\"\}
```